# How to build a tokenizer for simple expressions such as expr = "res = 3 + x_sum*11"

Tags: python, token

We want to build a tokenizer for simple expressions such as `xpr = "res = 3 + x_sum*11"`.

Such expressions comprise only three tokens, as follows:

(1) **Integer literals**: one or more digits e.g., `3` or `11`;
(2) **Identifiers**: strings starting with a letter or an underscore and followed by more letters, digits, or underscores e.g., `res` or `x_sum`;
(3) **Operators**: `=`, `+`, `*`, etc.

Leading or trailing white-space characters should be skipped.

To find which token each lexeme is associated with, we only need to find the first non-empty item in each tuple. Write a tokenize  generator (using `re.findall` and `map`) that returns all pairs (tuples) of lexemes and tokens. The output of `list(tokenize(xpr))` should thus be:

```
[('res', 'id'), ('=', 'op'), ('3', 'int'), ('+', 'op'), ('x_sum', 'id'), ('*', 'op'), ('11', 'int')]
```

Comment: And I want a pony. Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you have anything written so far? We might be able to help you if youre stuck, but i dont think anyone wants to do the whole thing for you

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`tokenize.tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.tokenize):

```
import tokenize
import token
import io
import collections

class Token(collections.namedtuple('Token', 'num val start end line')):

    @property
    def name(self):
        return token.tok_name[self.num]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {!r} ({} {}): {!r}'.format(self.name, self.val,
                                              self.start, self.end, self.line)


line = b'res = 3 + x_sum*11'
result = [Token(*item) for item in tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO(line).readline)]
result = [(tok.val, tok.name) for tok in result[1:-1]]
print(result)
```

yields

```
[('res', 'NAME'), ('=', 'OP'), ('3', 'NUMBER'), ('+', 'OP'), ('x_sum', 'NAME'), ('*', 'OP'), ('11', 'NUMBER')]
```

You could modify the `Token.name` property to match your specification exactly, but since the token names as shown above are already defined in the [`token` module](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/token.html), you may want to change your specification to match what Python uses (if you can).